# wget -i URI issues

Tags: powershell, uri, wget

When using the `wget -i` command in PowerShell, I insert this:

```
wget -i C:\Users\ttaal\Desktop\ASP1\Links.txt
```

This refers to a .txt file I have saved called Links.txt which has this:

https://resources.pearsonactivelearn.com/r00/r0066/r006623/r00662374/current/OPS/images/Pure_Maths_1-001.jpg

https://resources.pearsonactivelearn.com/r00/r0066/r006623/r00662374/current/OPS/images/Pure_Maths_1-002.jpg
...

However, when I enter this, It asks to enter a URI, however, I have no idea what to enter.

When I try to enter anything, It says either the URI is invalid or it can't send a content-body with this verb-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using get-content to read the links file and then pipe to a foreach loop:

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\ttaal\Desktop\ASP1\Links.txt" | Foreach-Object { Wget $_ }
```

Comment: When I change the directory then run the command, I am unable to find the files in that directory. Do you know how I could access the downloaded files? Thanks

Comment: You will need to specify the output directory.  In powershell 'wget' is an alias to Invoke-WebRequest, so if you need to know how to use that command that is what you want to search.  The switch to specify where to put the files is -OutFile